# Bug zoomcharts linkClasses not showing links

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts

I am using zoomcharts NetCharts to display the netchart legends. I see that `nodeClasses` seem to be working fine, but not `linkClasses` (I don't see the link being displayed under the Legend section)? The source code for testing it out is here: https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/examples/legend/net-chart-legend.html

Using latest Zoomcharts version, on latest Chrome browser.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the latest version. We will verify this tomorrow and publish a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the upcoming version 1.9.

For now you can use the nightly build which includes the fix: https://cdn.zoomcharts-cloud.com/1/nightly/zoomcharts.js